# Процессор и система охлаждения

Tags: пк

Можно ли заменить систему охлаждения (радиатор+кулер) процессора чем-то другим, допустим медной пластиной или чем-то другим, небольшого размера с толшиной<200мм

Comment: @Programer Уважаемый участник, вопросы общекомпьютерной тематики надо задавать на [БитКоде][1].

[1]: http://user.hashcode.ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это зависит от процессора (т.е. максимальной рассеиваемой мощности), площади пластины, толщины её и условий на поверхности - естественная конвекция или искусственная.

А дальше возможно рассчитать температуру.

Если надо, то я дополню ответ формулами оценки температуры процессора для подобной системы.

Но для большинства обычных процессоров, как мне кажется, небольшой пластины для теплоотвода окажется недостаточно - не зря радиаторы из мед да ещё и с искусственной конвекцией.

В зависимости от условий, можно сделать медный теплоотвод и радиатор с нагнетателем где-то подальше, где есть место для них. Можно вместо медного теплоотвода использовать тепловую трубу. Или ещё в комплекте с элементами Пельтье (холодной стороной на процессор). Можно водяное охлаждение забубенить, выведя насос и теплообменник куда-то ещё.

Но какой-нибудь теплообменник всё равно нужен - тепловые потоки там достаточно большие. Либо используйте процессоры с меньшей тепловой мощностью - от нетбуков, например. Там охлаждение попроще будет.